# How to create just an authentication with facebook sdk in iOS?

Tags: ios6, facebook-sdk-3.0

In my iOS app I just want to create a login button and when this button is pressed, the user must login using his own facebook account.
I don't want to use other facebook features after this, only authenticate the user's account information.
Thanks!

Comment: Check out developers.facebook.com/docs/ios and get the latest SDK and learn from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/). It goes through a step-by-step tutorial of how to install the Facebook SDK for iOS and how to use it to log in.